# MySQLdb not working while trying to upload Raspberry Pi weather data to SQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I recently have been programming a program that uploads data from my Raspberry Pi weather station, with Python, to a PHPMyAdmin database. My website will then read the data in the database with PHP. I have the PHP section of the code working (will read data from the database), however my issue is my Python part of the program. I am using the *MySQLdb* plugin for Python. However, when I attempt to connect with the same details as PHP, it does seem to establish as a connection, as there is no error, however the rest of the code does not run.

How would I go about fixing this?

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = 'server169.web-hosting.com', 
    user = '***********', 
    passwd = '**************', 
    db = '************', 
    port = 3306 # should be same as in /etc/mysql/my.cnf on server.
)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')

data = cursor.fetchone()

print str(data)

database.close()
```

Comment: Does `print str(data)` output anything?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

`host = 'server169.web-hosting.com',`

This is a real host I think ? By default, MySQL (the DB you use) is disable on anything other than a localhost incoming connexion : you can't connect to the db from "outside" the server.

You PHP script works because it is run on the server so it can connect locally to the database.

Three ways to solve this :

- connecting to you server with a SSH tunnelling `raspberrypi:3306` to `server169.web-hosting.com`
- allowing mysql to listen on `server169.web-hosting.com:3306` (you'll need root access to do this, +change the firewall rules)
- using an interface on the server that'll add the data for you (like a php script you call from you RaspberryPi with an `HTTP POST` request and a JSON object).

The last one is probably the best way for you, as you don't have to go too deep in configuration / need specials access on the server.

Comment: @Pharaoh php is the website on the server `web-hosting.com`, python is on his home RPi, you can't use the ID/pwd from php to log with python from "outside", as I explain... (or at least, that's how I understand the question)

Comment: You're right, my bad. Maybe you should explicitly explain why it works with PHP to make sure I'm the only one who makes this mistake.

Comment: @Pharaoh thanks! if you have any other idea than my 3, feel free to edit my post ;)

Comment: I'll add that :)

Comment: @RobB understand that you Rpi will not be able to directly save his data on the mysql DB without changes you are probably not allowed to do